# Simplifying a RPG fight method

Tags: java, methods, simplification

im struggling with a chunk of code, which works as it should as of now, but could maybe be improved? I´m making a RPG game for a school assignment, and I can hand it it now. But if it can be improved (shortened), I would be happy for some pointers :)

All the calls to other methods works (for example player.isDead and so on).

The two methods in question are:

I call .fight from the Game class to start the fight (with a list of monsters).

```
public void fight() {
    monster = monsterList.get(random.nextInt (monsterList.size()));                
    System.out.println("A" + " " + monster.getName() + " " + monster.getEnter());
    //turn 0 = player 
    //turn 1 = monster       
    fight:
    while(!player.isDead() && !monster.isDead()) {
        while(turn == 0) {
            String input = inputreader.getCommand();            
            if(input.contains ("run")) {
                player.setGold(player.getGold()-50); 
                System.out.println("You throw 50 gold at the monster and escape in the confusion.");
                break fight;
            }
            else if(input.contains ("attack")) {                    
                break;
            }
            else if(input.contains ("help")) {
                printHelp();
            } 
            else if(input.contains ("inspect")) {
                printDescription(monster);
            }              
        }   
        gameAttack();
    }

}
/**
 * The fight between the monster and the player
 */
private void gameAttack() {                       
    System.out.println("You attack! ");
    int playerDamage = random.nextInt(21)+10;
    monster.changeHealth(-playerDamage);
    System.out.println(player.getName() + " hits " + monster.getName() + " for " + playerDamage + " damage! "
        + monster.getName() + " has " + monster.getHealth() + "/" + monster.getMaxHealth() + " hitpoints left! ");
    if(monster.isDead()) {
        System.out.println(player.getName() + " is victorious! " + "\n" + player.getName() + " looted the monster for " 
            + monster.getGold() + " gold ");
        player.setGold(player.getGold() + monster.getGold());
    }    
    else{    
        turn = 1;
        System.out.println("The monster attacks!");
        int monsterDamage = random.nextInt(21)+20;
        player.changeHealth(-monsterDamage);
        System.out.println(monster.getName() + " hits " + player.getName() + " for " + monsterDamage + " damage! "
            + player.getName() + " has " + player.getHealth() + "/" + player.getMaxHealth() + " hitpoints left!");
    }
    if(player.isDead()) {
        System.out.println(player.getName() + " has been slain by " + monster.getName() + ".\n" + "Game over, bro!");
    }
    else{
        turn = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write this? If so, why don't you know how it works? Which part is it that you don't understand. Also: Wow, GOTO statements!

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it. I´m studying programming, so I don´t know everything yet.. hehe. This is a result of experimenting :) Tell me about GOTO?

Comment: With GOTO I meant this `fight:` and `break fight;`, which is rather unusual in Java. (Correction: this is not really a GOTO, just a special form of break, sorry for the confusion). Again, what part is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, its the while loop with turn==0. Is it a better way to make the player fight the creature without stating that it should be turns? Btw, I edited the question to be more precise :)